# Drupal #attached doesn't work with some themes

Tags: javascript

I've written a module which loads CSS and JS files using the #attached property.  This works fine across most themes, but for some themes the files are not loading.

e.g.:

```
$page['header']['#attached']['css'][] = array(
  'data' => drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule') . '/css/mymodule_default.css',
  'type' => 'file',
  'options' => array(
    'group' => CSS_THEME,
    'preprocess' => TRUE,
    'every_page' => TRUE, 
  ),
);
```

As there is very little by way of explanation on #attached (most articles repeat the same stuff) I can't figure out where the problem may lie.  Using `drupal_add_css()` and `drupal_add_js()` works, but is not recommended for caching reasons, and I prefer to pass settings using attached for this reason.

The #attached properties are showing in the `$page` array but are not being rendered.

In summary, are there situations when certain themes block the correct rendering of #attached elements that would normally be applied to a render structure by drupal_process_attached()

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Possible idea? If there isn't a `header` region in the theme, then `drupal_render()` would never be called to process this.

Comment: Thanks, I've already checked that.  Anyway the problem remains if I change the region to suit the theme.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The example code you are giving indicates, that you want to have this CSS included on every page. In this case do not bother using `#attached` at all and just call `drupal_add_css` from `hook_page_build`. An even better option is to include the CSS in the module-info file with the following line:

```
stylesheets[all][] = css/mymodule_default.css
```

In contrast if the asset is to be added to the page only when a given element is rendered (e.g. a form), then use `#attached` on that element. This way the path to the asset gets stored along with the render-array if the element is cacheable. On subsequent page requests, the element will be retrieved from the cache and the asset is attached to the page. If you would use `drupal_add_css` together with cacheable elements, the asset would be missing on subsequent page builds.

Note that even when using `#attached`, `drupal_add_css` is called internally from within [drupal_process_attached](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_process_attached/7). The responsible code, but actually boils down to this excerpt:

```
// Add both the JavaScript and the CSS.
// The parameters for drupal_add_js() and drupal_add_css() require special
// handling.
foreach (array('js', 'css') as $type) {
  foreach ($elements['#attached'][$type] as $data => $options) {
    // [...]
    call_user_func('drupal_add_' . $type, $data, $options);
  }
  unset($elements['#attached'][$type]);
}
```

The `call_user_func` will invoke either `drupal_add_js` and `drupal_add_css` respectively, depending the value of `$type`. It follows that there is no additional benefit from using `#attached` *unless* the asset is used by a render-array which is to be stored in the cache. Assets specified via `#attached` are guaranteed to be loaded if the associated render-array is rendered. They will not be added to the page when the associated render-array is not rendered.

In your specific situation you are attaching the CSS not to an element but to a page region. However the header-region apparently is not rendered by every theme, probably because it is not widely used. The header-region is rendered in [page.tpl.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_process_attached/7). If a theme chooses to ignore a region, like the Versatile and the Corporate Clean do, the CSS will not be attached.

To sum up:

- Use `#attached` when adding assets to cacheable render-arrays (especially forms and form elements)
- Add stylesheets / scripts to the module-info file or call `drupal_add_js` and `drupal_add_css` whenever adding assets globally.

Comment: Great explanation, it's arguably missing one small bit - to include CSS/js on every page it's at least equally appropriate to add via a module/theme .info file

Comment: `hook_init` should not be used to load CSS/JS files using drupal_add_.. My question relates to adding files to the $page array for example using `hook_page_alter()`, hence the $page variable, as this is a recommended way to attach CSS/JS files and bypass the caching that occurs with `drupal_add_js()/css`.  Also using .info is valid but only if you don't want to use conditional logic to load files, such as as a result of a variable state.

Comment: Thanks for the response above, but the question isn't asking how #attached works vs `drupal_add_js/css`, but whether there are situations when certain themes block the correct rendering of #attached elements that would normally be applied to a render structure by `drupal_process_attached()`

Comment: @Pluto: Please name an example theme for which your code works and another where it does not.

Comment: The code works in Omega, Garland, Bartik, Zen but not in Corporate Clean and Versatile.  As mentioned, the attached properties appear in the $page array but aren't rendered, same if the region is changed to $page_top or another region specific to the theme in question.

Comment: Versatile's `page.tpl.php` just contains one line, basically a render of $page['content'] so how did you do it there?  Ditto on what you actually tried with Corporate Clean.

Comment: @jimajamma I don't think you understand the question, but thanks ever so much for your insights.  Have a look at how drupal_processed_attached() works.

Comment: @jimajamma is actually correct. Versatile ignores the header-region and therefore the CSS is not attached.

Comment: Updated the answer and switched from `hook_init` to `hook_page_build`. Actually it does not really change the situation here but it is better practice to only add CSS to HTML pages, and let alone Ajax callbacks etc.

Comment: I understand but I had already stated twice that I'd updated the code to address the existing regions, and the themes I am using are not just in their basic form.

Comment: Just *do not #attach* to any region. This is simply not the way to do it.

Comment: Well the advice on drupal.org is that we certainly shoudn't use hook_init() as you first stated.  The advice also suggests that drupal_add_js/CSS is not best practice, and although you say don't attach to any region you don't say why not, if header isn't available we must choose another region.

Comment: @Pluto: I agree, that `hook_init` is bad style, I disagree that `drupal_add_js` is to be avoided altogether, see my updated answer. I will not update the answer anymore unless a third-party is proving me wrong.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12560/discussion-between-pluto-and-znerol)